# creating for loop using selenium python to click dropdown items

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a for loop which:-
1) clicks the dropdown item
2) add a comment
3) submit a comment

This whole loop will happen in the same page itself. The XPath is correct and I can execute these lines individually once but it fails in a loop. What am I doing wrong here?

No particular error message given

```
add_comments = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('add')
comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@class='addComment expand']//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Add a comment')]")
submit_comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='Comment']")

i = 0

for add_comment in add_comments:
  for comment in comments:
    for submit_comment in submit_comments:
     WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
     add_comment.click()
     comment.click()
     comment.send_keys("Awesome Art")
     WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
     submit_comment.click()
     i += 1
     if i > 4:
        driver.close()
```

Link is https://society6.com/society?show=2 but might not work since its within my account. Here is the screenshot[image: +add comment button below images is the one which i want to click]
The '+add comment is the part where i want to put comment

Html is here-

```
<form class="addComment expand" data-id="9647336">
                            <img src="https://ctl.s6img.com/society6/img/g2taHIrokQ01R_67jS8ulaWI2wk/h_150,w_150/users/avatar/~artwork/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/sul97/avatar_asset/d837ee10016843a3bba9ae3310cc338d" width="25" height="25">
                            <textarea placeholder="Add a comment..." data-button="9647336"></textarea>
                            <button id="b9647336">Comment</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: what is the link? need to know the html

Comment: Why do you use `i` counter? How much drop-down menus there on page? How much comment text input fields and Submit buttons on each drop-down? Also your `WebDriverWait(driver, 5)` do nothing as well as `WebDriverWait(driver, 2)`

Comment: If I understand, your loop is running only once. Most probably your `add_comments`, `comments` and `submit_comments` lists have only one element each. Can you check it out?

Comment: I added i counter to control the amount of time the loop gets executed. So that it doesn't become infinite loop. There are huge number of comment options in one page so it cant be one, program can just click +add comment dropdown button but can't write text in it so somethin wrong in logic of code. Drop down options just have one image, textfield and submit button.

Comment: and whats the problem in WebDriverWait?

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala I want to help but don't have time and really don't want to create account. Share some account.

Comment: Thanks sers, unfortunately its a paid account and i have only one. I will find my solution from any other place so u don't have to invest ur time :)